# How to make a UEFI compatble ISO with grub-mkrescue?

Tags: grub2, uefi, grubrescue, grub-efi

I have been following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MakeALiveCD/DVD/BootableFlashFromHarddiskInstall) to produce a customized version of Ubuntu.

As of now, the structure of the CD is complete. I just have to generate a bootable ISO image with the command:

> sudo grub-mkrescue -o live_cd.iso /path/to/cd/root

I got a perfectly working iso image **which boots well in VirtualBox, under UEFI mde.**

The problem is **when I copy the iso to my USB flash drive** (using dd command)  **it does not boot in my real machine under UEFI mode.** I get this:

[image]

However, I can boot the flash drive fine in legacy bios mode.
I have installed `grub-efi` package as well.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: cross: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223453/how-to-make-a-uefi-bootable-iso-image-with-grub-mkrescue

Answer (score 1):

1. mount Stick

   sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdX /mnt
2. Install another Grub2 to USB:

   sudo grub-install --no-floppy --force --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdX
3. Copy iso to stick

   cp -v ~/live-cd.iso /mnt
4. Add following to `/mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

   ```
   set default="0"
   set timeout=10

   insmod fat
   set iso_path=/live-cd.iso
   loopback loop (${usb})${iso_path}
   set root=(loop)
   set bootopts="boot=casper iso-scan/filename=${iso_path} noprompt"

   menuentry "Boot ISO from HDD/USB" {
   linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz $bootopts
   initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.img
   }
   ```

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MakeALiveCD/DVD/BootableFlashFromHarddiskInstall#Appendix_2._How_to_Make_bootable_USB_flash

It may solve your problem

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't the optimal solution I'm seeking.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.